# Angle of deflection from the vertex of a square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have the impression this question is somehow trivial but for some reason I'm not able to figure it out. So I'd appreciate your help.

**Problem**

Suppose I have a square with sides $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. Now I shoot a ball from anywhere inside the square (except from its centre) to a corner (vertex) of the square formed by two sides, let's say $a$ and $b$ at angle $\alpha$ from $a$. What would be the angle of deflection after it hits the corner?

(In this problem I'm excluding external factors such as friction, drag and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case when the ball doesn't hit the corner, but a point $P$ at a small distance from it. In that case the ball, after hitting two sides of the square, bounces back along a line parallel to the trajectory of the ball before hitting the sides. As $P$ approaches the corner, the distance between the two parallel lines gets smaller and smaller. In the limit, that distance vanishes and the ball, when hitting a corner, bounces back along the same path it came from.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not trivial at all.

After two reflections, reflected ray *remains parallel* to the incident ray but have *opposite sense* of the velocity vector. No exception to rays emanating from points such as $P$.

After encountering a  corner the ray *retraces its own path*. Rays go along lines that make $ (\alpha, \pi-\alpha) $ to horizontal along parallelogram edge paths as shown.